# How to record in real time the audio sounds and then play them with the in-built speakers or headphones in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avspeechsynthesizer, sfspeechrecognizer

I want to build an iOS app using AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer simoultaneously. Something like a megaphone that records in real time voices and sounds in the ambient and play them all in real time, without any type of sound processing. I want to create a temporary file with a single button start/stop. Suggestions? How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

- For recording purpose, you can follow this tutorial :
  [Speech-to-text](https://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/)
- For Playing your recorded file, follow this : [text-to-speech](https://www.appcoda.com/text-to-speech-ios-tutorial/)

Comment: Let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: is there any way to add some extra sound effect in the recorded sound?

Comment: I didn't have idea about this. @kruti